# UKeyboard "flickers" when resigning first responder status

Tags: ios, objective-c

This may be an ios7 issue as I have not noticed it before. I have a UITextField, and its appearance is set like so:

```
namingTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

When the user is done editing, I do this:

```
//Animate inputView out of the way
    [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationTime delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{


        //Resign first responder
        [namingTextField resignFirstResponder];

        //Animate GUI out
        inputBckGrnd.frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, inputBckGrnd.frame.origin.y, inputBckGrnd.frame.size.width, inputBckGrnd.frame.size.height);
        inputLbl.frame = CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, inputLbl.frame.origin.y, inputLbl.frame.size.width, inputLbl.frame.size.height);

    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if(finished){
            [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationTime delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                self.inputViewDimmer.alpha = 0.0f;
                self.inputBlur.alpha = 0.0f;
            }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                if(finished){
                    //Input UI knocked out
                    didLoadInputUI = NO;

                    //Kill GUI
                    [inputBckGrnd removeFromSuperview];
                    [inputLbl removeFromSuperview];

                    inputBckGrnd = nil;
                    inputLbl = nil;        
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
```

When the UIKeyboard resigns, it flickers to the light appearance. I tried it with using `UIKeyboardAppearanceLight` and it doesn't flicker at all. I also tried moving it out of the animation block but it made no difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes resigning the keyboard when other things are going on can cause lots of UI glitches, one way around this is to perform a `@selector` with a delay of `0` instead of just outright calling `resignFirstResponder`. It's strange that this works but I've had it solve many strange keyboard animation issues for me before. Example:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideKeyboard) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

Of course, in `hideKeyboard` you would just call:

```
[namingTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Great thought I will try this when I get home and report back

Comment: So the issue still persisted. After some research, I noticed that the dark appearance is translucent while the light doesn't seem to be (this is the keypad, mind you). I think what I am seeing is the uielements behind it maybe?